# Passing data between mapView and tableView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, tableview

I have a viewController with a mapView and a tableView on it.  I'm trying to get data like the users current location from the mapView and be able to pass it to the tableView so I can print out the calculated distance.

I tried using this code...

```
let distance = currentLocation.distanceFromLocation(endLocation)
```

But this doesn't work because currentLocation is created in locationManager's didUpdateLocation function, while endLocation is from the tableview data that I"m pulling from CloudKit.  I can't use the two pieces of data together because they are from different functions.

How do I go about setting the userLocation so that I can use it outside the locationManager's function?

I have this..

```
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation
    let ulong = userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    let ulat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
}
```

But I can't use the data outside that function.

Comment: Save your current location and end location to different CLLocation objects and then implement following code.                                                func calculateDisatnceBetweenTwoLocations(source:CLLocation,destination:CLLocation) -> Double{

        var distanceMeters = source.distanceFromLocation(destination)
        var distanceKM = distanceMeters / 1000
        let roundedTwoDigit = distanceKM.roundedTwoDigit
        return roundedTwoDigit

    }

Answer (score 1):

Save your current location and end location to different CLLocation objects and then implement following code.

func  CalculateDisatnceBetweenTwoLocations(source:CLLocation,destination:CLLocation) -> Double{

```
var distanceMeters = source.distanceFromLocation(destination)
var distanceKM = distanceMeters / 1000
let roundedTwoDigit = distanceKM.roundedTwoDigit
return roundedTwoDigit
```

}

Comment: I understand what you're suggesting, I updated my post, please see the updated question please.

Comment: I haven't started working on swift so don't know much about the function scope. But can give you the idea regarding your question. If you can't use the data outside the function, let you first save it in user defaults and then use it in other function.

Comment: That fixed my issue.  Thanks!